# My dialog box below does not work, Please correct

Tags: android, dialog

```
pbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {   private AlertDialog show;
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {   
            if ((input1.getText().length() == 0) || (input1.getText().toString().equals(" ")) || (input2.getText().length() == 0) || (input2.getText().toString().equals(" "))|| (input1.getText().toString().equals(""))||(input2.getText().toString().equals("")))
            {

            show = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle("Error").setMessage("Some inputs are empty").setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
            }
            double result = new Double(input1.getText().toString())+ new Double(input2.getText().toString());
            output.setText(Double.toString(result));

        }
```

I've also tried passing the context which also doesn't work

Comment: display dialog box ONLY if condition true . Use show method after if condition.

Comment: Is your condition was satisfied??

Comment: condition was satisfied, but dialog was not displayed

Answer (score 1):

Use In This Way:-

```
   b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              if ((input1.getText().length() == 0) || (input1.getText().toString().equals(" ")) || (input2.getText().length() == 0) || (input2.getText().toString().equals(" "))|| (input1.getText().toString().equals(""))||(input2.getText().toString().equals("")))
                {
            showAlert();
                }
        }
    });
}
private void showAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertbox.setMessage("Some Inputs are Empty");
            alertbox.setTitle("error"); 
    alertbox.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

        }
    });

     alertbox.show();

  }
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error in the first line :( . It tells me ; expected

Comment: You Can pass message In private void showAlert(String msg) which you want to show otherwise alerbox.setMessage("YourMessage")without create method.

Comment: I'm still not able to make it work, may be i'm making some obvious mistake, could you please post what exactly should I write inside my if condition

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to call the `create()` first like:

```
show = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle("Error").setMessage("Some inputs are empty").setPositiveButton("OK", null).create();

show.show();
```

**EDIT**:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Error");
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Some inputs are empty");
alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
        // if this button is clicked, ....

    }
  });   


AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: The app still crashes without any dialog box, I get NullPointerException in the console

Answer (score 0):

I used your code as it is and works fine. 
Please make sure that you are not import

**import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;**

if you imported above listener then it will not works
you have to import below,

**import android.view.View.OnClickListener;**

Then it will definitely works.

Comment: I have imported android.view.View.OnClickListener; still it's not woring.. does it have to do with the android version? I use 4.1.2